# Can Kibana be synced to Elastic App Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, kibana, elastic-appsearch

So I have Kibana set up with my data in it. About 3 indices.

Recently I've deployed Elastic Enterprise Search And im testing out Elastic App Search, but I have no data in it.

My question therefore is, can I somehow migrate or sync my data inside Kibana into Elastic App Search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, migration of Elasticsearch indices to Elastic App Search is not available as of now.

Even though it looks like Kibana is holding the data, but actually Elasticsearch is the datastore behind it. App Search is a layer on top of Elasticsearch which manages the indexes, schema, documents etc.

If you're directly ingesting data into Elasticsearch, at this moment it is not possible to automatically migrate to Elastic App Search.

Comment: 7 months later... Is this answer still true ?
No built-in way to migrate all of my existing ElasticSearch indices to ElasticAppSearch ?